# If else statement does not give desired output

Tags: python

```
from datetime import date
import calendar

my_date = date.today()
today_day = calendar.day_name[my_date.weekday()]

if today_day == 'Wednesday' or 'Thursday':
    place = 'A'
else:
    place = 'B'
```

Initially, I wanna set place as 'A' when 'today' is 'Wednesday' or 'Thursday', otherwise as 'B'. But the designed code kept returning 'A' despite it is 'Saturday' today(14/10/2017). How could I fix it?

Comment: Replace your if statement with `if today_day in ['Wednesday', 'Thursday']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you are asking `if (today_day == 'Wednesday') or 'Thursday'`.  `'Thursday'` evaluates to `True` since it is not an empty string, so `place` will always be `A`.  What you need to do is

```
if today_day == 'Wednesday' or today_day == 'Thursday':
    place = 'A'
else:
    place = 'B'
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your condition to:

```
if today_day == 'Wednesday' or  today_day == 'Thursday':
```

or:

```
if today_day in ('Wednesday', 'Thursday'):
```

In your version `'Thursday'` is a non-empty string and as such always truthy when evaluated as an atomic part of a boolean expression.

Answer (score 2):

Your if statements is eqivalent to

```
if (today_day == 'Wednesday') or 'Thursday':
```

and False or 'none empty string' will always evaluate as True.

I would implement this as

```
weekday = date.today().weekday()
place = 'A' if weekday in [3,4] else 'B'
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have written is equivalent to boolean `or` of two conditions

```
(today_day == 'Wednesday') or 'Thursday'
```

`Thursday` always evaluates to `True` (because that's how non-empty strings are evaluated in python).

Instead, you could write the (more idiomatic)

```
today_day in ('Wednesday' or 'Thursday')
```

or

```
today == 'Wednesday' or today == 'Thursday'
```